# React js big in filesize? Correct way to setup gulpfile.js?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6

I have created a gulpfile.js and a package.json (inclusing all my npm packages), but once building (even without all the additional npm packages), I have a very big final javascript file. It's around 1,5 mb, with React.js, ES2015 and a few other things..

Can anyone tell me why my final build is so big, and how a gulpfile should look like with all the latest versions of the frameworks as of today?

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    return browserify('./source/app.js')
        .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('build.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

and my packages.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
}
```

Thank you (a lot)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of important steps you're missing if you want to create minified production builds.

## Environment

The unminified version of React contains a certain amount of code that can be safely omitted for production. You'll find it in conditional statements like this:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // ... 
}
```

The first is to include [envify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify) as part of your pipeline, then set up the appropriate environment variable from gulp.

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  return browserify('./source/app.js')
    ...
});
```

When this runs, it will substitute the `process.env.*` references for their literal values.

```
// with process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { }
// becomes
if('production' !== 'production') { }
```

## Minification

Smart minifiers, like [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) will spot this in their static analysis pass and recognize that the statement contains dead code (code that will never run) and can safely remove it before further minification.

The minifier will also remove comments, rename most of your variables and delete lots of whitespace to shrink the filesize.

Once you've eliminated the dead code and minified the rest, you should find that the gzipped size of the resulting bundle is much more reasonable. Otherwise, you might be interested in checking out [Preact](https://github.com/developit/preact) (which is only 3kb) and [some of the other alternatives to React](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-alternatives-preact-virtualdom-deku/).

Comment: Hi Dan, thnx for your extensive answer. I have added envify and uglify, but still, the minimal file size I get is over 700kb (minified..). The original file was a liite over 2 mb. btw. envify only reduced the file size by a few kb.. I think something is not correct, since I also read about people posting on their filesizes around 80-150 kb for their whole project.. What can I expect? My project is fairly small.. is it because I use ES?

Comment: Envify won't actually remove that much code, but it will prevent some expensive things from happening at runtime. The bulk of your minified bundle comes from React and the other libraries you've included, the ES syntax polyfills provided by Babel won't be huge.

Comment: If you're really keen on cutting the bundle down further then you can look into using [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) instead of Browserify (to eliminate dead code) and [Buble](https://buble.surge.sh/) instead of Babel (a lightweight alternative). Also remember that people often quote their filesize after gzip and minification.